# Not Works im2bw keyword in octave

Tags: octave

trouble using im2bw for image thresholding

**im2bw: THRESHOLD must be a string or a scalar in the interval [0 1]
error: called from**

```
MO = imread('test.jpg'); 
M = rgb2gray (MO);

M3 = im2bw(M,127);
imshow(M3);
```

Comment: I would think that the error was self-explanatory: "THRESHOLD must be a string or a scalar in the interval [0 1]". The value of your threshold is 127. That is not between 0 and 1. I would suggest dividing your threshold by 255. That will probably give you the results you expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation of im2bw (emphasis mine):

```
The input image IMG can either be a grayscale or RGB image.  In the
later case, IMG is first converted to grayscale with 'rgb2gray'.
Input can also be an indexed image X in which case the colormap
CMAP needs to be specified.

The value of THRESHOLD should be in the range [0,1] independently
of the class of IMG.  Values from other classes can be converted to
the correct value with 'im2double':

     bw = im2bw (img_of_class_uint8, im2double (thresh_of_uint8_class));
```

Grayscale images can have pixel values of class *double* in the range [0,1], or values of class *uint8* in the range [0,255].

The `rgb2gray` function returns the first kind (i.e. values in the range [0,1]).

Therefore your threshold needs to be defined in that range.

As the documentation above suggests, you can convert your "127" uint8 threshold to a double one using the `im2double` function.

In other words, your code should probably look like this:

```matlab
MO = imread('test.jpg'); 
M  = rgb2gray (MO);  % Note this isn't really necessary, im2bw does it for you
M3 = im2bw(M, im2double( uint8(127) ) ); % or simply im2bw(M, 0.5)
imshow(M3);
```